# Change Default Date format getting from SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, date

I got date values from the database in this format `'Jan  1 2019 12:00:00:AM'`,
But I use `'2019-01-01'` format in my web application.

I am using **Laravel**, **SQL Server**, **Centos7** and **Php 7**.

In `php.ini` ddate format is `ibase.timestampformat` = "**%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S**".

Please help to change this default format.

Comment: Sounds like your column isn't a Date and time data type, but an `(n)varchar`. Fix the data type, fix the problem.

Comment: My column datatype is "date".

Comment: Then it has no format. The format you see is defined by your presentation layer.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with the date? SQL query or just display?

Comment: In presentation Layer no format is use. This value is get directly from query using dd function in Laravel.

Comment: I need to process it using PHP .

Comment: Please check if the colon : before AM is correct in ''Jan  1 2019 12:00:00:AM''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be in your T-SQL statement. This behavior can appear if your `date` is stored in `date`, `datetime` or `datetime2` column, when it is read and converted to string (explicitly or implicitly).

So, we can have:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT CAST(@Date AS VARCHAR(36))
```

and get `Dec  4 2019 11:29AM`. That's why in T-SQL we can set the [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) when converting date to text. For example:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()

SELECT CAST(@Date AS VARCHAR(36));          -- Dec  4 2019 11:33AM
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @DATE, 121);    -- 2019-12-04 11:33:52
```